# How to copy records from Server1 db1 table1 to Server2 db2 table2?

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

```sql
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, name,age)

SELECT Table1.Id,Table1.name,Table1.age FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
ON (Table1.id=Table2.id) WHERE Table2.id IS NULL
```

The above code was very helpful to me to transfer data from one table to another while those two tables were on the same database.

However, now I must do this same task, but across different servers! Can someone please edit the above code so that it's easy to understand? Thanks.

P.S. Please use :

> Server1 access => 'ip1', 'user1', 'pass1', 'db1'
>
> Server2 access => 'ip2', 'user2', 'pass2', 'db2'

Comment: short answer you cannot directly do this in mysql. you can try to use federated storage engine see documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html

Comment: @MiniGunnR: bansi is right. If you want to directly do this, you have to use Federated Storage Engine. Read: [How to Use FEDERATED Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)

Comment: Thanks guys. I am currently reading the documentation given by bansi, however, it says that I have to replicate the two tables exactly as it is. So, if I want to just sync a couple of columns from a table containing 30 columns, it seems I can't do that. :-/

Comment: visit the following link hope it would help.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937443/is-it-possible-to-copy-records-from-one-db-table-on-one-server-to-another-db-tab>

Comment: Even if we are able to copy the table records from DB1 to DB2, how we would verify that all records are perfectly copied or if any missing than how to find out which one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, no issue. Just tell me one thing, you want to use this query in PHP file...

Comment: Yes. I want to run this script every 5 or 10 seconds through cron so that these two tables are at sync. I don't know if that is the best way to do it though. :)

Comment: Previously you did not tell us that you want to run these tables after every 5 - 10 seconds...

Comment: If it can be done once, doing it repetitively is not an issue I guess.